# Is K&R out of date when it comes to function declarations with double return types?

Tags: c

Is K&R 2nd edition out of date when it comes to function decelerations where functions return `double`?

Page 71 states that:

> the calling routine must know that `atof` returns a non-`int` value.
>   One way to ensure this is to declare `atof` explicitly in the calling
>   routine.

Here is another function on p.72 illustrating this:

```
/* rudimentary calculator */

main()
{
    double sum, atoif (char []);
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int getline (char line[], int max);

    sum = 0;
    while (getline (line, MAXLINE) > 0)
        printf("\t%g\n", sum += atof(line));
    return 0;
}
```

Is this even necessary in c now, or should the declarations be in the header file along with other functions that return ints?

Comment: K&R-C is out of date in many aspects, most notably old-style declarations (which are obsolescent since C89), implicit declarations (removed in C99), and old-style definitions (also obsolescent since C89). And yes, nowadays standard library functions are usually declared (with a prototype) by including the headers.

Comment: Note that K&R dates back to the time where *processing time* was expensive, so not including an entire header (which has to be read, parsed, and stored into memory) would have had its advantages.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things in this book that are outdated, as one would expect. However, you seem to misunderstand what this is about.

It is absolutely required, even more so than years ago, that when a function is called, the compiler needs to know a function prototype when the function is called.

For functions that are part of the Standard C library, the appropriate header file must be included. For functions that are not part of the Standard C library, like the "atoif" that you declared, a declaration within a function is an awfully bad practice and it would be much better to declare it in a header file and include it, put it is just as perfectly legal as it was back then.

Comment: What am I confused about exactly?

Answer (score 1):

But ... as a now scaly dynosaur, I can remember that in old K&R days, we already used header to declare functions ! So for this part K&R is still valid because including a header is no more no less than declaring a bunch of function prototypes.

The main difference between old K&R C and modern C, is that in modern C we declare the return type **and all parameters**, whereas in K&R only return type was declared (and we had to control ourselves with no compiler help that all parameters had correct type ... if not SIGSEGV !)